# iOS: Foundation framework issue

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, foundation

I have a problem with my Foundation.framework. It is imported, the file exists, I havent deleted a header file. I didnt touched it at all. But xcode gives me unexplainable errors I dont know to fix.

Here is a screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

you must have edited some framework file in your project, try to backtrace your actions, or figure out some lines of code which werent supposed to be present in the framework...the compiler will also ask you to delete some files from derived data, do it...then it would go

Comment: I don't think that I edited the framework, I checked the modification date of all header files of the Foundation.framework. all are the same 25.5.2014. Also I get this error on 2 different machines!

Comment: I have faced this similar catastrophe , and the reason was same, I had accidently added a few charachters to the framework .h files, removing that everything got fixed

Comment: I am not able to see any error in the header fils. I tried to change the file and it prompted me to enter my admin password. I haven't entered it. I haven't entered my password and I am sure I haven't entered it before. I was able to build the application yesterday, and I am sure that I haven't changed anything big in the project since then.

Comment: Fixed it! I imported the Crashlytics framework in …-Prefix.pch! Its odd that this is resulting in such an error!

Comment: In my Cash it was the editing issue, anyways glad you figured it out